# How to use python for curl alternative

Tags: python, curl, urllib

in curl i do this:

```
curl -d "text=great" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
```

How i can do this same thing in python?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) library you can do somethng like this:

```
from requests import get
get("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/", data={"text": "great"})
```

Comment: though i found a solution using built in urllib package.Thanks :)

Comment: You did not specify any additional requirements :) Just "how"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using urllib

```
data = urllib.urlencode({"text":"great"}) 
u = urllib.urlopen("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/", data)
the_page = u.read()
print the_page
```